# Should the FQDN for ADFS and ADFS servers be the same?

Tags: adfs2.0

I have two ADFS 2.0 Proxy servers with the name auth.somedomain.no and two ADFS 2.0 servers with the name adfs.somedomain.no.

However, the https://auth.somedomain.no/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml does not expose the https://adfs.somedomain.no/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Must the official name of both ADFS and ADFS proxy be equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. I did the change so that all adfs servers and proxy use the same federation name like sso. The MS documentation is not very precise in this regard.